# How to capture screen with color inversion done using accessibility in android

Tags: android, inversion-of-control, screenshot, accessibility

I want to analyze the color contrast of my app when color inversion under accessibility is turned on. For that I need to have screenshot of my app in color inverted mode. But all elements in the screenshot are displayed in normal color, regardless of the mode.

Is there a way I could take the screenshot of what is shown on the screen i.e. color inverted using android accessibility?

Answer (score 5):

Color inversion is applied too late in the rendering pipeline to be included in a screenshot or video recording.

You can duplicate the value-only inversion effect by inverting your image (ex. using GIMP or Photoshop invert filter) and then rotating the hue of your screenshot by 180 degrees.